# HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver() Missing

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wiring up Ninject with MVC4 and have it working to the point it's trying to actually resolve dependencies.  However, I am getting the following exception:

> Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'.

Anyone ran into this and have a work around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver` was replaced with `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` in the RC. So I guess the Ninject package you are using is simply not designed for the RC. It was one of the breaking changes.

So here are the steps to make Ninject work with ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API RC:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Empty template
2. Declare an interface:

   ```
   public interface IFoo
   {
       string GetBar();
   }
   ```
3. Then an implementation:

   ```
   public class Foo : IFoo
   {
       public string GetBar()
       {
           return "the bar";
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then add an API controller:

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       private readonly IFoo _foo;
       public ValuesController(IFoo foo)
       {
           _foo = foo;
       }

       public string Get()
       {
           return _foo.GetBar();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Install the `Ninject.Mvc3` NuGet package (`Install-Package Ninject.Mvc3`)
6. Define a custom API dependency resolver as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2417226):

   ```
   public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
   {
       private IResolutionRoot resolver;

       internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
       {
           Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

           this.resolver = resolver;
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
           if (disposable != null)
               disposable.Dispose();

           resolver = null;
       }

       public object GetService(Type serviceType)
       {
           if (resolver == null)
               throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

           return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
       }

       public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
       {
           if (resolver == null)
               throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

           return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
       }
   }

   public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
   {
       private IKernel kernel;

       public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
           : base(kernel)
       {
           this.kernel = kernel;
       }

       public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
       {
           return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
       }
   }
   ```
7. In your `~/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs/CreateKernel` method that was created when you installed the NuGet add the following line after the `RegisterServices(kernel);` line:

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
   ```
8. Configure your kernel:

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
   }
   ```
9. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and navigate to `/api/values`
10. You are presented with `the bar`.

Obviously when the RC hits RTM I hope there will be a `Ninject.Mvc4` NuGet that will shorten those 10 steps to maximum 5.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've ever seen...  I guess you've earned those 336k points :-P  Thank you a ton Darin!